# Designing a generic validation tool in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

The task is to design a generic validation tool . It should be

- able to validate n different type of entities.
- Each entity has its own set of validation constraints.
- each Entity can be composed of zero or more other entities
- The validation operation will validate n or less than n entities every time, each validation will return a Validation result containing details of failure (if any),The final response should be a combined result of all the validations
- The sequence of validations might differ.
- The entity classes are already existing and cant be modified.

Is visitor design pattern a good choice here? I will have to create classes corresponding to each entity which will have "has-a" relationship with each entity and this class implements an interface with accept method. Is this too much convoluted logic?

I am using Java 8 , so is function composition a good choice here. Another option is having a Collection of validate functions for each entity and then composing them on the fly , and using it.
Is this the right direction? Any other options that you guys can point me to?

Comment: But what you gonna validate? Fields like idk int age? You mean something like this: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation001.htm?

Answer (score 1):

Visitor pattern may work, but I would make it a bit simpler. The best approach I see would be to make all entities implement an interface similar to this one:

```java
interface Entity {
    Collection<Constraint> getValidationConstraints();
    Collection<Entity> getInnerEntities();
}
```

Each entity will provide its own constraints and inner entities. In your validation service, you can just generically get the constraints and apply the validation logic based on them. This will improve the code maintainability.

If you can't update the entity classes to implement that interface, you can take them as `Object` in your validation service and use `instanceOf` to identify them (a bit ugly, but it works).